# Ejs compiling error

Tags: html, compilation, ejs

I am having a rather annoying error occur when I try to add an if statement inside of a forEach loop.

I want to have a delete button not show up for the name of the user currently signed in (for example you cannot delete your own account).

Now the forEach loop runs fine on its own, but the second I add the if statement i get this error:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in C:\Users... while compiling ejs

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% users.forEach(function(foundUser){%>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="pt-4 pb-3">
                            <%= foundUser.first_name %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="pt-4 pb-3">
                            <%= foundUser.username %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="pt-4 pb-3">
                        <%= foundUser.phone %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="pt-4 pb-3">
                            <%= foundUser.address %>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 250px;">  
                            <a href="/users/<%= user._id%>" class="btn btn-outline-success mt-3 mb-3 visible">View</a>
                            <a href="/users/<%= user._id%>" class="btn btn-outline-warning mt-3 mb-3 visible">Edit</a>
                            <% if(user != foundUser) %>
                                <form class="d-none toggle-danger mt-3" action="/users/<%= user._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                                    <button href="/users/<%= user._id%>" class="btn btn-outline-danger visible">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            <% } %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% }); %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</main>
</div>
</div>
```

I have no idea what is happening and this is the only ejs on the page except for an <%- include ... %> statement. Please help! It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you miss a { on if statement.

It should be

```
<% if(user != foundUser){ %>
```

but you have

```
<% if(user != foundUser) %>
```